# Echo in capistrano task make empty file

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

I try to create REVISION file with full commit hash on deploy.

```
#early..
revision = %x[git rev-parse HEAD]
set :revision, revision

namespace :assets do
    task :install do
        on roles :all do
            puts fetch(:revision, "")   #it's good, print ee51dc1308a07cb0dfadd60b2a9d1b3485614034

            execute :sh, "-c 'echo #{fetch(:revision, "")} > #{release_path}/REVISION2'" 

            execute :sh, "-c 'cat #{release_path}/REVISION2'" #empty output

            execute :php, "#{release_path}/public/index.php assetic build"
        end
    end
end
```

As a result I have file REVISION2 with no content.

Capistrano Version: 3.4.0 (Rake Version: 10.1.0)
Dev machine: Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Deploy to CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem by writing REVISION file on the local and then upload it with the following task

```
task :save_revision do
    revision = %x[git rev-parse HEAD]

    File.open("REVISION", 'w') { |file| file.write(revision) }

    set :revision, revision  #save for future
    puts revision #print

    on roles :all do
       upload! "REVISION", "#{release_path}"
    end
end
```